# Using existing sqlite table in Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my Android app, I want to use my existing sqlite database.I followed http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ this tutorial and succeed in copying the database file.But my problem is I cant access copied database.Can anyone check my code and help me accessing my database? thank you..

here is the method i used to copy my database,

```
public class Databaseopenhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.basim.database/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "db3";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public Databaseopenhelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

        // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
       // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
       // to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

I want to know how to access the copied database file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.

```
private DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
sqLiteDatabase = dataBaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME", null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            try {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    int abc=
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TABLE_COLOUM_NAME")),

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
                sqLiteDatabase.close();
            }

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: I used your method.But it says there is no such table.I think when I use your method a new emplty database is created with same name as copied database.And the database which is copied is being deleted.

Comment: Sorry. I think you make any mistake. I do same thing in my project and it is working...

Comment: can you please post ur code? so that I can refer it.And it will be very useful. Thank you....

Answer (score 1):

check this method. this way you can use your SQLiteOpenHelper implementation transparently as usual. no special treatment.
[using a preloaded sqlite database with SQLiteOpenHelper](http://blog.kdehairy.com/2012/08/19/using-a-preloaded-sqlite-database-with-sqliteopenhelper/)